# sqlite3 - creating a cursor and executing

Tags: sqlite

> Hello! new to SQLite3
>
> there are some example programs where a "cursor" is created before
>   executing.. and other programs that do not create a cursor.
>
> QUESTION: do I need to create a "cursor" or it can be omitted?
>
> Example below without a cursor:

```
    con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

    con.execute("create table person(firstname, lastname)")
```

> Example below WITH a cursor:

```
    db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    db.execute('drop table if exists test')
    db.execute('create table test(t1 text, i1 int)')
    db.execute('insert into test (t1, i1) values (?,?)', ('one', 1))
    db.execute('insert into test (t1, i1) values (?,?)', ('two', 2))
    db.commit()
    cursor = db.execute('select * from test order by t1')
    for row in cursor:
        print(dict(row))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `execute` without a `cursor` is a non-standard shortcut, i.e., this might not be available with other database drivers.
But if you aren't executing a `SELECT` where you need the output, it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks! will use the cursor to make it more standard :-)